# Iptable code for whitelist website in linux

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I need to allow only one website and to block remaining all for that I need iptable coding in Linux OS.kindly let me if any body knows.

Comment: First of all it's iptables and not iptable. Second, iptables is no programming language so there is no _code_ for the end user to use. It is a tool that you can _configure_. Try to get your terminology right. And last, get your logic straight and don't jump to conclusions as to what tool you need BEFORE having described and investigated the problem. It leads you nowhere, ever.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose iptables is **not** the correct tool (keep OSI in mind).

If you want to block/allow traffic to websites a proxy (ex. [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)) should do the job.